# Python logging: Set handlers for all loggers of used modules

Tags: python, logging

I have my main script that interprets cli commands with argparse and then starts the application by calling the according stuff form an other module (made by myself).

My question now is how I can attach a handler to the logger from that module. The logger is retrieved with

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I hence put following in my main script:

```
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger = logging.getLogger('MyModule')
logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

However there is 0 logging output from 'MyModule'. Log levels are correct, eg there should be an output.

In `MyModule` I have the following:

```
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

However removing that makes no difference.

So how can I correctly attach a handler to the logger of `MyModule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting no output is most likely that you haven't set a level on the logger, so it will default to `WARNING`. Try doing `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` and see if that causes output to be produced. I know you said that log levels are correct, but I can't see any other reason why no output would be produced. You can try posting a small self-contained script that demonstrates the problem, if you like.

`NullHandler` only needs to be added for library modules to cater for their use in an application that doesn't configure logging. It is not needed in modules of an application that configures logging.

In general, you can add a handler to the root logger and it will be used by loggers in all modules.

**Update:** The comment to Kobi K's answer indicates that a level has been set on the handler - this is not enough, as you need to set a level on the logger, whose level is checked first. Only if the event is allowed through by the logger's level will the handlers (and their levels) come into play.

Comment: That was the first question I've asked in my answer... at the first comment you will see that he said that he used `setLevel()`, the problem lays in his logger naming, using `.getLogger(__name__)` from the module results in a new logger without an ancestor.

Comment: @Kobi K: I see you mentioned setLevel in your answer, but I see nothing to indicate that the questioner has used it on the logger - the comment merely says it's been set on the handler. Also no actual logging statements are indicated, so one assumes that `logger.debug()` etc. are being called. All handlers apart from the root logger have an ancestor - which is the root logger, if not any other logger.

Comment: the remark in "Update" solved the issue. Log level must also be set on logger, not only on the handler.

Answer (score 5):

The best example of adding `handler` to logger is the one from [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging), See below.

Did you added `consoleHandler` with `setLevel()` and the `Formatter()` ?

As for this line:
`logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())`

Why are you using it this way? I would recommend to follow the next code for adding an handler the right way.

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

Comment: The NullHanlder thing is actually from the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library. And yes I am attaching a log level and a formatter to the handler. It works for the main module but just not for the other ones that are imported. The docs and your example above do not show anything about setting up a logger from a different module.

Comment: What you want is a global logger for your modules and sub-modules?

Comment: Each module should have a different one so that one can see from which module each log entry is from.

Comment: Passing `__name__` to `getLogger()` in a sub-module is the problem, python logging module works in a hierarchy. 
All loggers are descendants of the root logger.

When you call `getLogger("myLogger")` it will create a new descendant from the root logger,
If you want to create a logger inside a sub-moudle you need to call inside the sub-moudle `getLogger("myLogger.mySubModule")`

Comment: OK. But this requires the module to know how it's callers logger is named? And if there are different callers, that does not really work.

Comment: "Someone" needs to create the logger, there is no escape from that, When a sub-module trying to `getLogger()` the method is trying to find it's ancestor if it cant find it a new logger will be created. It's very handy, but sometimed to avoid that I'm passing the logger Object as an argument to the sub-module instance, you can try that.